# linux sockets accept always failing

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, server, client

i've got a relatively simple server, which should open a server socket and accepting one client socket connection.

```
if(!(STARTUP))
{
// CAN Socket öffnen
can_soc = initialize_CAN();

// TCP Socket öffnen
tcp_soc = initialize_TCP(strtol(argv[1],NULL,10));

STARTUP = 1;
}


// Jede empfangene CAN Botschaft auf TCP umleiten
while(!(EXIT_FLAG))
{

if(!(CLIENT_CONNECTED)) // Wenn keiner verbunden ist, wird gelistened
{
    // LISTEN //
        listen(tcp_soc,2);

    std::cout << "Waiting for incoming TCP connection...\n";

    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    tcp_client_soc = accept(tcp_soc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);

    if(tcp_client_soc < 0)
    {
    std::cout << "ERROR: accept failed\n";
    EXIT_FLAG = 1;
    return 0;
    }
    else
    {
    std::cout << "Connection from " << inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr) << " accepted!\n";
    // --> NEUER CLIENT AKZEPTIERT //
    CLIENT_CONNECTED = 1;
    }
}
else            // ansonsten: CAN auf TCP leiten
{
    std::cout << "nop" << std::endl;
}

}
```

The problem now is, that the program always terminates at "ERROR: accept failed", which means that accept is always delivering -1 with no connection being established (O_NONBLOCK is not set).

```
int initialize_TCP(int pPort)
{
    int tcp_soc;

    std::cout << "Creating TCP socket and binding to PORT: " << pPort << "... ";

    tcp_soc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if(tcp_soc == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Could not create socket!\n";

    EXIT_FLAG = 1;
    }


    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;    //do not specify IP (got a server here)
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(pPort);

    // BIND //

    if(bind(tcp_soc,(struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Binding failed! Restarting network service ...\n";

        system("/etc/init.d/networking restart");   //Restarted Network Servcie wenn Binding nicht geht

        std::cout << "Binding again... ";
        bind(tcp_soc,(struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
        std::cout << "OK\n";
    }


    std::cout << "OK\n";
}
```

So where is the problem? maybe there is a unknown connection coming in every time? or is it a syntax problem?

Comment: You are calling `listen()` inside your `while` loop. It should be outside the loop instead, or better inside of `initialize_TCP()` right after `bind()` succeeds. Either way, when `accept()` (or any other socket function) fails, what is the value of `errno`? You should output that to `cout`. Also, you should output the result of `strerror()`, too. Also, don't restart the networking service, that is not your app's responsibility. Make the user do it. But if you do restart, you likely will have to recreate your listening socket from scratch. You are not checking the retried `bind()` for failure.

Comment: You also need to apply the same error-checking to `socket(), listen(), bind(), ...`

Comment: thanks @RemyLebeau , i implemented errno and it shows 88, "Operation on non socket type", which means the socket is not correctly initialized i assume?

Comment: @rele92: error 88 is `ENOTSOCK`, so yes, you must be passing an invalid socket descriptor to `accept()`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, the socket wasn't present so ERRNO delivered code 88.
That was caused by not returning the socket descriptor correctly.